# Structuring join tables for Many-to-Many relations

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm developing an application and have ran into a couple of issues which I believe is due to the way I have set up my schema.

An overview of the app is a university course system. Each course is made up of a number of modules, each module is made up of a number of units and each unit is made up of exercises.

A requirement is that exercises, units and maulers can be re-used in different ways to form new content. So, for example Exercise A could exist in Module B and Module C.

Initially I have gone for a database that looks like this, I've removed all but primary keys and foreign id's for brevity.

```
+---------+
| courses |
+---------+
| id      |
+---------+

+----------------+
| course_modules |
+----------------+
| id             |
| course_id      |
| module_id      |
+----------------+

+---------+
| modules |
+---------+
| id      |
+---------+

+--------------+
| module_units |
+--------------+
| id           |
| module_id    |
| unit_id      |
+--------------+

+-------+
| units |
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+

+----------------+
| unit_exercises |
+----------------+
| id             |
| unit_id        |
| exercise_id    |
+----------------+

+-----------+
| exercises |
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
```

Having got so far with this it seems to have become apparent that I've messed up.

Given a specific `unit_exercise` there is no way of me knowing which course it belongs to as I can't reliably move up the "chain" as it's impossible to know which `module_unit` this refers to.

My question is should my join tables actually link to their parents too? So for example I change the joins to

```
+----------------+
| course_modules |
+----------------+
| id             |
| course_id      |
| module_id      |
+----------------+

+-------------------+
|   module_units    |
+-------------------+
| id                |
| course_modules_id |
| module_id         |
| unit_id           |
+-------------------+

+----------------+
| unit_exercises |
+----------------+
| id             |
| module_unit_id |
| unit_id        |
| exercise_id    |
+----------------+
```

Initially it seemed redundant to include this information but the more I look at it it seems like it must be required.

Comment: You did not messed up -- one unit-exercise may belong to many modules/courses. Just make sure to keep `{unit_id, exercise_id}` etc.. unique.

Comment: I need to be able to go to  a specific unit (for example) and be able to find the correct course that is related to.

Without the secondary foreign keys to the table's "parent" there's no way to do this it seems as their is ambiguity as to which `course_module` a particular `course_unit` belongs to

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in two ways.
The first one as you mentioned. The second one, you can have all your reference tables course,unit,module,exercise like you initially did and then have a final Course_details table with Course_id, Module_id,Unit_id and Exercise_id. This way you can add individual units or exercises without the need to attach them to a course or modules etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice I intend to develop a very similar system and I imagine I'll go through the same question in the future. So I threated your issue as if it were mine.

Perhaps it is not really necessary to store the complete route to an exercise. Not in the database... It seems to me that session data would be quite appropriate in your situation. Users probably arrive at a certain `exercise` from the appropriate `unity` page. So, why not sending parents' identifiers as parameters to the descendants' pages?

I'd also choose composite primary keys. Graphically speaking,

> [image: EER Diagram - MySQL Workbench V6.1]

Comment: Yes this is how I currently have it working. I'm passing through all the id's course, module, unit, etc. but it seems quite cumbersome.

It's not always the case that users will come straight through from the "parent", as I want to be able to easily get their next non-complete unit/module/exercise that's out of the scope of this question though

My framework doesn't fully support composite keys or I would have used them.

Comment: I see... But don't you believe it simplifies a lot your data structure? Would it be possible to pass course / module / ... through URL? Maybe URLs won't get so pretty but things get easier :)

Other question, suppose a user is currently working on two units with some common exercises. After finishing the first unit, does he have to repeat these common exercises in the other unit? Or these are availed to the other units they belong to?

Comment: It simplifies the data structure yes but i dont think it really simplifies the code. It requires the use of a temporal variable to track what course the user is in currently. Something iw ant to avoid.

I want the user to be able to go back to where they were on any course they are taking when they come back. 

Yes a user would have to complete the exercises for another course.